# Playing Sound Instantly (without waiting to complete) on Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I partially achieved playing sound with keys with html and `.play`. However it waits for the track to be completed and doesn't let me play instantly on every click. However I want to trigger the sound as soon as I press  it each time.

```
<audio id=soundId1>
  <source src=sound/Saaa.wav>
</audio>
<audio id=soundId2>
  <source src=sound/Baaa.wav>
</audio>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var sound = {
    65 : 'soundId1',
    23 : 'soundId2'
};

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    var soundId = sound[e.keyCode];

    if (soundId) document.getElementById(soundId).play();
    else console.log("key not mapped : code is", e.keyCode);

}
```

Is there a way of achieving it with the above approach only without using any library?

---

I also looked into howler.js (I don't know if it's proper use) but I couldn't really understand how I can add multiple tracks into the dictionary. I understand how I can put the files into sounds dictionary however how to call it and link it to keyCode system above? Or should I add a `new Howl` for each sound individually?

What is the proper way of achieving it?

Comment: Try stopping the previous playing element then play the current one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work but I have not tried it:

```
function Sound(){
    this.src = ""
}

function playSound(source){
    var sound = new Sound();
    sound.src = source;
    sound.play()
}
```

A new sound instance is created instead of overriding the previous one.